# Remix + Ganache - Cannot call one contract from another

Tags: ethereum, remix

I have an innocent looking contracts that work painlessly in Remix. Test contract can easily call Another if I use JavaScript VM in Remix.

I also have ganache-cli running on port 7454. If I connect Remix to ganache-cli, each of these contracts work well individually. But I cant call Another from Test. Remix console says `transact to Test.send errored: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

My contracts look like:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Another {
    uint public balance;
    function sendToAnother() public {
        balance += 10;
    }
}

contract Test {
    function send(address another) public {
        Another(another).sendToAnother();
    }
}
```

One suspicion I have is - am I picking up the address of the Another contract correctly? I am copying it from Remix's `Deployed Contracts` tab.

Comment: Provide some screenshots. Even better, link to unlisted video on YouTube. Record a screencast so we can understand the problem better.

Comment: I have just put the screenshots on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63433/remix-ganache-cannot-call-one-contract-from-another